# Ionic 5, ¿cómo enviar cookie de sesión a un endpoint?

Tags: ionic, session, iis, cookies, http-post

Estoy desarrollando una app con Ionic 5, la cual consume un servicio remoto. Este servicio controla la sesión mediante cookies.
¿Cómo hago para en la peticiones post (@ionic-native/http/ngx o @angular/common/http) reenviar esa cookie de sessión?
Al parecer, una vez logueado la primera vez, cualquier otro post que ejecute lo hace en una sesión distinta.
Fuerzo a un withCredentials: true, pero entonces me da error de CORS.

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

La única solución es usar withCredentials: true, y en la parte del servidor agregar http://localhost:8001 (o el puerto que uses) o ionic://localhost (IOS) a una whitelist de hosts permitidos en la parte del servidor api.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta